# I have 2 app.run method.how to halt in first method until promise is resolved?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

```
angular.module('app', [
        ...   ])

.constant('AppConstants', constants)

.config(appConfig)

.run((UserService, User) => {
    'ngInject';
    console.log('apprun')
    UserService.acl()
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('data')
            User.setACL(data)
            console.log(data)//finsish this first then go to second run call
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })

})
.run(appRun)

.component('app', AppComponent)
```

1. I need to complete `Usercervice.acl` call first and then run second run(apprun) method need to be called here is code from `UserService.acl()`

   let acl = () => {
       return $http.get(AppConstants.api + `/acl/user-resources`)
           .then((res) => {
              return res.data
            })
    }

Comment: keep second on the success of first.

Comment: Can you please explain using some code it would be great thanks

Comment: it didn't worked any other way to hold execution in first run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.constant('AppConstants', constants)

.config(appConfig)

.run((UserService, User) => {
    'ngInject';
    console.log('apprun')
    UserService.acl()
    .then((data) => {
        console.log('data')
        User.setACL(data)
            console.log("done with first run")//finsish this first then go to second run call
            /*here is my second run block i.e. on success of first one*/

            var acl = () => { 
                return $http .get(AppConstants.api + /acl/user-resources).then((res) { 
                    return res.data 
                })
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })

})
.run(appRun)

.component('app', AppComponent)
```

Comment: what i want to do is get that data first before any state transition happen

Comment: did some digging and found that run methods are async and parallel so i can't stop them so what is did is created a loading page . which will continue to load until my async callback response